# Param for tf.contrib.summary.graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, eager-execution

I am using tensorflow 1.12 and the eager execution mode. I want to summarize the graph to the tensorboard log. I found a function called `tf.contrib.summary.graph`, however, it requires a parameter called `param`. What should I pass for this parameter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/summary/graph), the `param` parameter is for the graph object, which in eager can be a `tf.Graph`, `tf.GraphDef`, or a string containing a serialized GraphDef protocol buffer.

Note that in eager execution, by definition there isn't a single computation graph any more because the ops execute immediately instead of building a graph, so this is unlikely to be useful unless you're building traditional `tf.Graph` computation graphs in addition to running logic eagerly.  We may introduce some ways to record graphs in eager mode for TF 2.0, but there still won't be a single graph.

Comment: One more hint... how to simply get any proper tf.Graph or tf.GraphDef in eager?

Comment: There isn't really a tf.Graph or a tf.GraphDef to "simply get" in eager - eager mode just doesn't have a global graph.

If you use the new `tf.function`, we're working on an ability to write out the function graphs to TensorBoard, but it's still under development.